# "safety concerns related to switching of the drug product to OTC status" - do I need "the" before "OTC"?

Tags: definite-article

> safety concerns related to switching of the drug product to **the** Over-the-Counter status.

Do I need **the** before "Over-the-Counter", or is it the same as with the word **form**, which is used without the definite article?

> Remember Alf? He's back, **in pog form**!

Comment: I think since it refers to a very specific group of drugs, it requires the definite article. Regarding the word "form", I guess that, that zero article usage stems from the fact that it is being used in a certain prepositional phrase which has a fixed construction pattern. In other words, it's not due to the word itself but the phrase in my opinion.